# Delay between sequential kivy animations

Tags: python, kivy

When chaining animations in kivy,  like:

```
anim = Animation(pos=(0, 0) + Animation(pos=(100, 100)
anim.start(widget)
```

There is a delay between each animation. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: There is no delay between sequential animations. You might have an issue somewhere else in your code blocking the EventLoop from running. Please provide a minimal working app demonstrating this problem, or ask for help on our IRC channel #kivy on freenode.

Comment: You are missing two closing parens in the above code...

Comment: Are you animating an Image per chance?